# Django Rest: How to disable the POST api with {pk}

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

How do I get rid of `[POST] /api/contact/{pk}/` from the api with Serializer? (get rid of the second API)
My serializer definition is as follows:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('chatuser', 'contact', 'is_blocked')
```

And my ViewSet is as follows:

```
class ContactViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
```

[image: Django REST Swagger UI]

Comment: add the url conf relative to that view pls

Comment: I think some of your configuration is wrong. There should not be an endpoint to post `/api/contact/{pk}`. Most likely, put or patch

Comment: these urls are generated from the Router, I didnt set it up. Sorry for the late reply though... I tend to dump this framework and just do it myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a ReadOnlyModelViewset perhaps? From the docs:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#readonlymodelviewset

> The ReadOnlyModelViewSet class also inherits from GenericAPIView. As with ModelViewSet it also includes implementations for various actions, but unlike ModelViewSet only provides the 'read-only' actions, .list() and .retrieve().

It's a bit weird though because GenericViewSet shouldn't be giving you any actions out of the box, you should only get POST with ModelViewSet.

> The GenericViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView, and provides the default set of get_object, get_queryset methods and other generic view base behavior, but does not include any actions by default.

This probably means one of those mixins is providing the extra actions for you, see:

> In order to use a GenericViewSet class you'll override the class and either mixin the required mixin classes, or define the action implementations explicitly.

If you could check the definitions of those mixins or post them here, alternatively just try using ReadOnlyModelViewSet without any of the mixins and see how you get on.

Comment: Right, using a Mixin which derives vom ModelViewSet makes the `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` not doing anything. Thx for pointing this out!